# RDLC text overflow behavior

Tags: c#, excel, format, rdlc

I'm working on converting an older reporting format into RDLC and am running into a problem. In a few edge cases a numeric value overruns its allotted display space -- it's, let's say, '10000%', and I can't just set "CanGrow" to false and let the field truncate since the percent sign must be visible.

In the original reporting format a field too big for its allotted display space just displayed as a bunch of asterisks, so I've got a question in two parts:

1) Is there a way to format the data in RDLC so it displays an alternate string if it runs over a certain value?

2) Is there a way to apply that format for printing only, so that on exporting the data to, say, Excel (with Report.Render) the field will still say '10000%'?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, what worked here was combining the Globals!RenderFormat field with filtering based on the value. For example

```
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name Like "excel*" Or 
    (Fields!Percent1.Value > -10 And Fields!Percent1.Value < 100),
      Fields!Percent1.Value, "******")
```